# Add Link button in Kendo Grid cell (editable)

Tags: css, grid, kendo-grid

I have a simple grid containing an editable column with phone numbers.

I would like to add a small icon that the user can click on containing a "tel: link" so that their "phone hardware" can pick it up from there.

I have prepared a simple demo -> https://dojo.telerik.com/ogAgURep/2

**Goal**: When clicking the Phone-Button do not enter "Edit Mode" ..otherwise enter "Edit Mode"

**Problem**: Clicking Phone-Button enters "Edit Mode"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the schema set your "Tel" column to editable false.

```
schema: {
    model: {
        fields: {
            firstColumn: { editable: false },
            name: { validation: { required: true } },
             tel: { editable: false }
        }
    }
},
```

To make it so the column is still editable except when the phone icon is clicked, you could change icon to a javascript function that exits edit mode as well as the original action:

```
                template: function(args){
                    if(args.tel==null){ return ''; }
                    return args.tel + '<span class="k-cell-link-i"><a href="javascript:call(tel)" class="k-icon k-ii-phone">&nbsp;</a></span>';
                }
                function call(e){
                   var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
                   grid.cancelChanges();
                   //other logic originally in the template
                }
```

Comment: I want it to be editable, just not when the phone button is clicked

Comment: I updated my post. The second snippet should allow you to edit, but cancel editing if the phone button is clicked.